# Were the 'other' Worfs in 'Parallels' aware of the changes?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In Parallels, Worf jumped to other quantum realities when near Geordi's VISOR. Were the other Worfs aware and trying to find answers also? Or did the just move once, and so were not aware as such due to only small changes, whilst the original Worf leapfrogged through realities with greater and greater changes adding up?

Would all the Worfs have returned to the correct realities at the end, eg the one with the children and married to Troi, or would they have remained 'lost'? I ask as in the episode when they contact the original Enterprise, there is a Worf there, but no one seems to have noticed he is the wrong one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually yes, at one point Worf is on an Enterprise where Captain Picard died at Wolf359, and they are able to hail Worf’s original Enterprise.  That Captain Picard mentions that his Data had come to the same conclusion before the hail.  I would assume that their Data would only be able to come to that conclusion if they had a Worf onboard that was experiencing a similar shifting.

Comment: I just watched this episode last night, and it's so weird. You can actually *see* the Worf on the "correct" Enterprise in this scene, and no one seems confused or concerned. And if those two Worfs were jumping around, it seems like *all* Worfs should be jumping around. And if that's the case, how come this is the only Worf that can fix the problem?

Comment: @Plutor If Prime Worf was the only one affected, and switched with the other Worfs, then not all Worfs would've been jumping around.  Each of the affected Worfs should've only jumped once, when Prime Worf switched with him.

Comment: @Plutor: Maybe the Worf currently on the "correct" Enterprise was quicker at adapting to the new interface layout. If two Worfs were jumping around, that is only a sign that at least *some* Worfs are jumping around, not *all*. In any case, "our" Worf does not need to be the only one able to fix the problem, but he might happen to be the first one to stumble upon the solution.

Answer (score 4):

I would say that at least some of them were.  In the final part of the episode, when Worf goes back out in the shuttlecraft, and the universes blend, you can see multiple versions of Worf working in various points in the shuttle.  I've always taken that to mean that other Worfs and crews also figured it out and were also trying to fix the tear.